# Android Studio DDMS - Disabled Controls

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to interrupt an application execution on my emulator. I am using Bluestacks Emulator.

I opened the Android Device Monitor in Android Studio and but I can't make call as described in documentation. The controls are disabled. 
See the screenshot![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/djtEB.jpg